# WSTrust error using .NET framework 4.8 to connect to Azure SQL using Active Directory Password

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-server, c#-7.3

I have a console application that uses .NET Framework 4.8, and I need it to connect to an Azure SQL database, I have simplified the issue to the following sample:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString)) {
    con.Open();
    // ...
}
```

...where the connection string takes the form:

```
Server=MyDbAddressHere;Initial Catalog=MyDbName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrueServerCertificate=False;Authentication=Active Directory Password;
```

I am getting an exception when opening the connection:

```
AdalException: WSTrust response does not have recognized SAML assertion.
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the error I'm getting, and how to go about fixing it so I can connect to the database and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the password solved the problem; apparently it had something to do with the account recently having been changed to no longer require MFA.